# How to extract a list of values nested in a list of dict?

Tags: python

Here's an example code:

```
list1 = [{'name': 'foobar', 'parents': ['John Doe', 'and', 'Bartholomew' 'Shoe'],
         {'name': 'Wisteria Ravenclaw', 'parents': ['Douglas', 'Lyphe', 'and', 'Jackson', 'Pot']
        }]
```

I need to get the parent's values and print them out as strings. An example output:

```
John Doe and Bartholomew Shoe, Douglas Lyphe and Jackson Pot
```

I tried:

```
list2 = []

 for i in list1:
    if i['parents']:
         list2.append(i['parents'])
```

then, I tried to join() them, but they are lists nested in a list so, I haven't got to the solution that I'm looking for yet.

Could someone help me figure this out, please?

Comment: Any code you wrote to try to do it yourself? Please share!

Comment: I tried:
  
    empt_list = []

     for i in list1:
        if i['parents']:
             emp_list.append(i['parents'])

then, I tried to join() them, but they are lists nested in a list so, I haven't got to the solution that I'm looking for yet.

Comment: Please update it on the question!

Comment: Thanks, you need to first join inside the `parents` list, and then join the overall list! Check below! @Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first join all words in the dictionary, append all those strings to a list, and then join the final list

```
list1 = [{'name': 'foobar', 'parents': ['John Doe', 'and', 'Bartholomew', 'Shoe']},
         {'name': 'Wisteria Ravenclaw', 'parents': ['Douglas', 'Lyphe', 'and', 'Jackson', 'Pot']
        }]

sentences = []
#Iterate over the list and join each parents sublist, and append to another list
for item in list1:
    sentences.append(' '.join(item['parents']))

#Join the final list
print(', '.join(sentences))
```

The output will be

```
John Doe and Bartholomew Shoe, Douglas Lyphe and Jackson Pot
```

Or just use `list-comprehension`

```
parents = ', '.join([' '.join(item['parents']) for item in list1])
print(parents)
```

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: Great! Glad to help! It would be great if you could mark my answer as accepted by checking the tick next to the answer @Nick :)

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension and `join()`:

```
list1 = [{'name': 'foobar', 'parents': ['John Doe', 'and', 'Bartholomew', 'Shoe']},
         {'name': 'Wisteria Ravenclaw', 'parents': ['Douglas', 'Lyphe', 'and', 'Jackson', 'Pot']}]

parents = ', '.join([' '.join(dic['parents']) for dic in list1])
print(parents)
```

Output:

```
John Doe and Bartholomew Shoe, Douglas Lyphe and Jackson Pot
```

The inner `join()` combines the elements in each names list (eg. `['John Doe', 'and', 'Bartholomew', 'Shoe']` becomes `John Doe and Bartholomew Shoe`), and the outer `join()` combines the two elements resulting from the list comprehension: `John Doe and Bartholomew Shoe` and `Douglas Lyphe and Jackson Pot`.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated.